# Extracting data from items listed on multiple times?

Tags: excel-formula

So let me get right into it, i have a list with properties. the unique identifier is the car and each car takes a certain set of parts, but i would like to swop this list around to have the part as the identifier and the cars it goes on concatenated.

I want to go from this

| model | top part | bottom part | car make |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| f1 | P101 | P102 | Fiat |
| t2 | P106 | P109 | Toyota |
| f3 | P101 | P108 | Fiat |
| h7 | P108 | P102 | Honda |

To this

| Part no | Cars |
| --- | --- |
| P101 | Fiat f1 top part,Fiat f3 top part |
| P102 | Fiat f1 bottom part,Hona h7 bottom part |
| P106 | Toyota t2 top part |
| P108 | Toyota t2 top part,Fiat f3 bottom part |
| P109 | Toyota t2 bottom part |

Usually id figure it out but i have no idea what to even google for this.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a code-writing service, but -

> Usually id figure it out but i have no idea what to even google for this.

-- I'm going to take that as your question.

If (as the tag suggests) you want to do it all in an excel formula, you're going to have to use an array formula - look up 'concatenate if' or 'conditional concatenate' or similar, I did so and found [this](https://www.howtoexcel.org/formulas/how-to-conditionally-concatenate-a-range-formula/) which could be adapted to work for you (NB you'd need to do that twice, once for the top parts and once for the bottom parts).

On the other hand if you're ok with vba (personally I prefer vba code to over-complex in-cell formulas, it's easier to debug/adjust part-by-part) you'll need to use a loop and the like operator (will require a bit more research but worth it if you use excel a lot - google 'get started in vba', 'vba for loop' or 'for each cell in range vba', and 'vba like operator'.

Comment: well done! please consider marking this as an accepted answer so it shows as 'solved' to the SO community / website at large.